# What is the best way to write a GUI in Codename One : Use the designer or code the GUI?

Tags: user-interface, codenameone

I am looking for a way to quickly (but surely) design mobile app. So far I have been using the designer because I've been watching the video tutorials from CN1. But when I read the manual from CN1 the GUI is often coded by hand. And sometimes I struggle with the designer and the styles to make the GUI look how I want it to look.

So I was wondering if I should still go with the Designer for my future app or coding is much faster (the GUI I design are very simple) now that I know more about CN1 and the styles?

Thanks for your advices,

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are shifting focus to the new gui builder which generates a more hand coded styled app instead of the current StateMachine approach, so going forward we recommend coding the UI manually until the new gui builder will become more solid.

Comment: OK, that's a crystal clear answer! Thanks a lot @Chen!